# can we use office 365 list template on SharePoint on premise 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, sharepoint-on-prem

on office 365 site, there is a list with custom infopath form.

can i use template of this list on SharePoint On premise 2013?

when i tried doing so i received the following error

> **Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot
>   be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not
>   registered as safe. Correlation ID:
>   d6316f9d-f0df-60d4-d53d-84cf3fa61109.**

is it even possible to create list on SharePoint on premise  by using list template created on SharePoint online ?

actually i want to use infopath form that i have created for SharePoint online list?

Answer (score 3):

When the site template was created, all site features were saved with the template, regardless of whether they were activated or not. This situation can arise when you are moving site templates between different Office 365 plans or between SharePoint Server on premise and SharePoint online.

SharePoint Online is always ahead from on prem version, in new features deployment.

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/80082

Comment: i have uncheck Include Content and save the list as a template? still it not working for me..

Comment: also i have custom infopath form on list... so it is not possible to use SharePoint online list template with custom infopath form ..  correct me if I’m wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use the O365 list template with on-prem, but the views and forms will not work as you noted.  Load the list template you created into the gallery, use the list template you created, and create a new list (with content if you wish), and then open the list in SharePoint Designer 2013.  Replace the default views and forms with new ones and you should be able to access your list.